# debug cordova app on windows emulator creates outputpath issue

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I m trying to build ionic cordova app on windows. I have followed all the mentioned to run cordova app on windows emulator.
When I run `cordova run windows` through command line I get this error:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(724,5): error : The OutputPath property
 is not set for project 'SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination o
f Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='debug'  Platform='Win32'.  You may be seeing this messag
e because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-1RKA5NV\Desktop\myApp\plugins\cordova-sqlit
e-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj]
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I have spend almost two days searching for this issue but could not found anything that work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Kreepz yes that issue is now resolved.